# Update the same row after insert Inside the trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I have to use a trigger that will update the inserted row. Following is my trigger.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `kikan_db`$$

CREATE TRIGGER `t_trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `t_order` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
Declare kb_rate int;
Declare kb_amount int;

REPLACE INTO t_order_sales_month 
    SET order_no = NEW.order_no,
           search_sales_month = getSalesMonth(NEW.order_no);

SELECT kickback_rate INTO kb_rate from m_customer where customer_code = New.bill_customer_code;     
    SET kb_amount := 9999 / kb_rate;

 UPDATE `t_order`  SET `t_order`.kickback_amount = kb_amount where `t_order`.order_no = NEW.order_no;


END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Getting error at update.

It is mandatory for me to use `AFTER` instead of `BEFORE` type of trigger

Comment: You cannot action a table which initiates a trigger nor can you alter the new. value in an after trigger.

Comment: Is there any workaround ?

Comment: Maybe you can calculate the kickback (bribe?) on the insert to t_order. What does the insert look like - is at an insert with a values clause or an insert with a select clause?

Comment: insert with a value clause

Comment: I have to do it with trigger only.. *client's requirement*

Comment: Have to do what exactly with a trigger? There is no workaround for updating  t_order in a trigger.

Comment: I have to update the value of `t_order`.kickback_amount  in the trigger itself.

Comment: Why do you have to use an `after` trigger?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  seems like the client is in the driving seat.

Comment: If your client insists on doing this with a trigger you are going to have to move him/her to an RDBMS which does support this behaviour such as Microsoft SQL Server. Pity because a simple udf would do in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using only `after insert/update` trigger, (1) you can change the value  of virtual `new` row  on `before insert/update` :

```
Declare kb_rate int;
Declare kb_amount int;

SELECT kickback_rate INTO kb_rate from m_customer 
     where customer_code = New.bill_customer_code;     
SET kb_amount := 9999 / kb_rate;


SET new.kickback_amount = kb_amount;
```

(2)And execute the other SQL statements in a  `after insert/update` trigger:

```
REPLACE INTO t_order_sales_month 
   SET order_no = NEW.order_no,
   search_sales_month = getSalesMonth(NEW.order_no);
```

Comment: You could except op has stated that It is mandatory for me to use AFTER instead of BEFORE type of trigger

Comment: Yes @P.Salmon, but the `new`  object can't be modified in after insert trigger.